# iPhone App truncating at bottom while running in iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, layout, resize, alignment

I am developing an iPhone app which should support iPad (not compatible but with support for 1X and 2X option at bottom). My app supports iPhone 5,6 and 6 plus as expected, but when I run the app in an iPad some part of the screen is getting truncated at bottom. How do I fix this? It should show the full iPhone screen in iPad.

Comment: Did you get the solution?. Please let me know me also facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Make you app support iPhone 4s screen size. It seems that iPad runs iPhone app as in a 3.5 inch screen.